# Use different images depending on screen orientation in xcode 7.1

Tags: uiimageview, swift2, xcode7, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

I have a view controller which is my main layout and it consist of a stack view which has 5 horizontal image views, When I run my app in portrait mode there is no problem.

but my problem is when I turn the view or orientation to landscape image views are not usable and the picture is not useable for me. I have designed different images for landscape mode and I want to set different images to image views on screen orientation but don't know how.

I don't want to create two sub views and in them load this different image views which some users suggested for this issue.

Any suggestion how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation for changing image values : 
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

```
    switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation{
    case .Portrait:
        image_1.image = UIImage(named: "image_1")
    case .PortraitUpsideDown:
        image_1.image = UIImage(named: "image_1")
    case .LandscapeLeft:
        image_1.image = UIImage(named: "image_1_land")
    case .LandscapeRight:
        image_1.image = UIImage(named: "image_1_land")
    default:
        image_1.image = UIImage(named: "image_1")
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'll check and let you know !

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the first one. The orientation is found by calling [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation].You can update the uiimageview, one which you want to update in code uiimge->imagenamed method. Their are two ways to detect orientation changes in runtime,

1.Accelerometer

2.[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

Comment: Thanks for the answer but which method is more usable and accurate ?

Comment: I already listed in order, Accelerometer is more accurate and it can sense orientation change in all 3 axis including gravity. http://mobileorchard.com/how-to-make-an-iphone-app-part-5-the-accelerometer/

Comment: orientation change notifications usually posted with little delay.

Comment: Thanks again, i'm going to try what you said and let you know!

Comment: you are welcome, here is the obj c version, If you need you can convert this code to swift. http://codrspace.com/yuvirajsinh/device-orientation-detection-using-coremotion/